# iMessage stopped working on Mac

Tags: mac, messages, chat

Recently, iMessage won't sign in on my MacBook Air (10.8.4). I opened up Messages a couple of days ago, and my iMessage account was signed out. Upon trying to sign back in, I get a message reading:

> The registering device does not have the appropriate credentials.

And login fails. Anyone else have this issue?

[image]

Comment: Make sure date and time is auto

Comment: Since the iMessage software doesn't ship anymore, I'll point this to messages.app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here in this thread is how I ended up fixing this:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/22624648#22624648

I updated the Flash player for OS X, then went to **Preferences** → **Flash Player** → **Advanced** and told it to clear all browsing data from the local storage cache. After this, I rebooted and was able to login to iMessage on the Mac without the error.

Dumb that this interferes with iMessage, but this did fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps listed on this page - http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4476

If that doesn't fix your problem, try checking your Date & Time settings (Settings > Date & Time). Make sure "Set date and time automatically:" is ticked, and that your time zone is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Type:

> killall imagent

in `Terminal.app` (in /Applications/Utilities) and then start iMessage and log in again.

That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Terminal isn't the most beginner friendy, but to brave to go in and restart the specific process that runs the communications is a +1 in my book.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out that somehow I was logged out from my account. Just check if that's the case with you.
Open Messages application -> click on Messages (on the left upper corner) -> Preferences -> select Accounts -> and then, if you are logged out you will have to enter your iCloud password.

Hope this helps!